# How to use conditional formatting on a specific formula added?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I want to add a conditional formatting to a cell. In that cell I have a formula that provides 2 dates. The dates in the cell look like this `01/12/2024` and `01/24/2024`.

Originally when I had 1 date in that cell I've used this formula in Conditional Formatting `=AND($L$13>0,$L$13<TODAY())` to give me a color Red if it was past due and for Orange I would use `=AND($L$13-TODAY()>=0,$L$13-TODAY()<=3)` if this date was coming up in 3 days.

Can't figure out the formula to add into Conditional formatting for 2 dates in that same cell. What would the formula be for 2 dates in one cell?

Comment: Show us how these dates look in a cell and which date should the format refer to?

Comment: @MGonet unfortunately I cannot add an image the site keeps giving me an error but the dates in the cell look like this  01/12/2024 / 01/24/2024

Comment: Have you tired using 2 separate conditional formatting rules? Put the one which turns the cell red in first, then put a second one turning them orange in after that.   The order is key as one rule will override the other.

Comment: You can upload an image to imgur.com and link to it. Someone with enough reputation will likely embed it for you

Comment: Having "two data" (dates or whatever) in a single cell will always be troublesome, unless JUST for DISPLAY. Just avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your computer recognizes this format as a date and that it is the first date, try this formula in the formatting for red color:

```
=AND(--LEFT($L$13,10)>0,--LEFT($L$13,10)<TODAY())
```

and similarly for orange replace `$L$13` with `--LEFT($L$13,10)`